# Spring Graphql - How to use a custom DataFetcherExceptionHandler and override the default one?

Tags: graphql, graphql-java, spring-graphql, graphql-spring-boot

I'm new to spring graphql and I was trying to implement my own DataFetcherExceptionHandler so I can wrap all exceptions with my custom one.

I've implemented my custom class that implements DataFetcherExceptionHandler but it seems like it still uses the default one, the SimpleDataFetcherExceptionHandler.

How can I make my custom DataFetcherExceptionHandler the default one for the graphql exceptions?

My class:

```
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
@Component
public class GraphqlExceptionHandler implements DataFetcherExceptionHandler {

public DataFetcherExceptionHandlerResult onException(DataFetcherExceptionHandlerParameters handlerParameters) {
    Throwable exception = handlerParameters.getException();
    SourceLocation sourceLocation = handlerParameters.getSourceLocation();
    ResultPath path = handlerParameters.getPath();

    MyCustomException error = exposedException(exception, sourceLocation, path);
    return DataFetcherExceptionHandlerResult.newResult().error(error).build();
}

@Override
public CompletableFuture<DataFetcherExceptionHandlerResult> handleException(DataFetcherExceptionHandlerParameters handlerParameters) {
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(this.onException(handlerParameters));
}
```

Note: I'm not sure if I can use my custom exception like that, but I'm not able to test it while I can't make the exception handler the default one.

Answer (score 3):

With Spring for GraphQL you can implement a `DataFetcherExceptionResolver` or more specifically a `DataFetcherExceptionResolverAdapter` that you can for example annotate with `@Component` to register it automatically.

The `DataFetcherExceptionHandler` from `graphql-java` is used by Spring for GraphQL internally to delegate to your  `DataFetcherExceptionResolver` classes.

Inside your own `DataFetcherExceptionResolverAdapter`, you can get the informations that are available as `DataFetcherExceptionHandlerParameters` (`Path`, `SourceLocation` and so on) in a `DataFetcherExceptionHandler` from the `DataFetchingEnvironment` that is passed to `DataFetcherExceptionResolverAdapter` `resolveToSingleError` and `resolveToMultipleErrors` methods.

See here for more informations: https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/current/reference/html/#execution-exceptions

You can find an example implementation here: https://github.com/nilshartmann/spring-graphql-training/blob/main/app/publy-backend/src/main/java/nh/publy/backend/graphql/runtime/PublyGraphQLExceptionResolver.java